# Impact of using `table` in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

`table` in gnuplot allows you to plot the data to a temporary data file.

I wish to plot the following probability distribution function on `logscale`, so I proceeded like

```
binwidth=0.1
round(y)=y-floor(y) < 0.5 ? floor(y):ceil(y)
bin(x,w)=w*round(x/w)
set logscale
plot "data.dat" u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0/100000) smooth freq
```

This did not produce the desired outcome. However, this did:

```
set logscale
set table "temp.dat"
plot "data.dat" u (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0/100000) smooth freq
unset table
plot "temp.dat"
```

Essentially, I am wondering why I needed to use `table` in order to generate a temp file and then plot that file in log-scale, as opposed to simply plotting the `bin($1,binwidth)...` directly on log-scale.

Comment: What are `bin` and `binwidth`? Can you show the output you get from the two code snippets?

Comment: @user8153, I updated the post to reflect those expressions. But, I think I figured it out. What I want to plot on the log scale is the histogram obtained on the non log-scale. So if I do `set logscale` and then plot my histogram, the bins and incrementation happen differently as if the `logscale` is unset. Therefore, the two histograms, which I initially though should be the same, are not. Because one is drawn on a non logscale while the other is drawn on a logscale. This ultimately caused different binning and frequency incrementation.